# An exponential family of probability distributions have densities that are defined relative to a measure. What is a measure in this context?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I would like to understand the nature of measure, using the exponential family of probability distributions as a context (because I understand the latter well). I understand that we want equation (8.1) to integrate (over $x$) to $1$ - otherwise it would not be a probability distribution. Therefore we set that integral to one, and take the $e^{-A(\eta)}$ term out of the integral (since it is not a function of $x$), and rearrange to get equation (8.2).

My point is, I understand what's going on algebraically, but I have no idea what role the measure is playing conceptually. I have tried to learn measure theory many times (i.e., on my own), but I just don't seem to get what it is or its motivation. When the word measure is used, I have no idea what it refers to. The Lebesgue measure is supposed to be a generalization of length to sets that more complicated than intervals. I understand it somehow relates to probability. But what is a measure? In the particular context below, for example, what does it contribute to the description of the exponential family?

[image]
Source: [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter8.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter8.pdf)

Comment: Don't know what a measure is, but do know what a probability distribution is, hunh? You can think of a "measure" as being a "generalized" probability distribution that doesn't have to integrate to $1$, not even necessarily to a finite number.  Next question: what is "integrate"?

Comment: You're right, I don't know exactly what a probability distribution is in formal terms (because it is defined in measure theory!). But conceptually, I know what properties it should have, what it represents, etc...i.e., I know what the word probability means (and I can use it to do things, like derive a posterior, etc.). On the other hand, I don't know the first thing about measures

Comment: I know that integration was generalized from the Riemann sum (which is how I understand integrals) to a Lebesgue integral - but I don't know what this really means. So I also don't know what integration is, formally. But again, I know enough about integrals to understand what's going on when they're mentioned. I can't say the same about measures.

Comment: @kimchilover it would have been nice if you provided a useful answer with fewer snide remarks

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a measure, in general, as providing a notion of 'volume' or 'area'. Why is this useful in probability? Because often the volume and area of subsets correspond to the probability of an event occuring. For example what is the probability you land on the red squares of a dart board? In particular whenever you need to integrate to calculate a probability you use a notion of a measure.

In the early 20th century there was a rebirth of probability by Kolmogorov et al. that used Lebesgue's new measure theory to formalise probability. It works as follows: you have a set $\Omega$ of occurences $\omega$, and another set of subsets of  $\Omega$ that each correspond to events- you can view this literally as the event space that could happen in real life. random variables are functions from this event space that take values in real life, so when you talk about a random variable following a distribution, you're talking about the random variable's values when certain combinations of events happen, and the measure of those combinations. We have a function $\mathbb{P}$ that takes events, and gives you a probability of events happening. We call this a probability measure, and it has to satisfy the rules that Lebesgue indicated general measures have.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But given that the author is already talking about probability distributions, what does mentioning the measure add to the description? Let me put this differently - if the measure was not mentioned at all (i.e., the variables $\eta$ and $\nu$ do not appear), what information is now missing from the description?